# Python ( OpenERP ) Compute Field1 and Field 2

Tags: python

```
   date = field.Date('Start Date')
   product = field.Char('Product')
   namecompute = field.Char('name',  compute=_get_name)
```

> ```
> @api.multi
>
> def _get_name(self):
> ```
>
> `date + product = namecompute`

How to compute namecompute field ( odoo 8) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the example code to compute in Odoo v8:

```
from openerp import api

date = fields.Date('Start Date')
product = fields.Char('Product')
namecompute = fields.Char('name',  compute='_get_name')

@api.depends('date', 'product')
def _get_name(self):
    for record in self:
        record.namecompute = record.date + record.product
```